# Densitiy of order statistic when in a certain interval

Tags: conditional-probability, order-statistics, interval-censoring, indicator-function

$X$ is distributed with $F$, i.i.d. and with densities.

I am trying to discern an expected value for a certain order statistic $X_{k}$ under the condition that $X_{k}$ is closest to some value $\alpha$.

To do so, I am trying to write the density of $X_k$ as the normal order statistic density $f_{(k)}(x)$ and a multiplicative term which only depends on $\alpha$.

So to start with, I am trying to get the density of $X_k$ following the regular heuristic proofs for order statistics with my additional condition.
For some epsilon interval $A$ around $x$:
$$P(X_k \in A \land X_k ~\text{closest to } \alpha) \\
= nP(X_1 \in A)P(\text{k-1 below k})P(X_k ~\text{closest to } \alpha) \\
= f_{(k)}(x) P(X_k ~\text{closest to } \alpha) $$
This is basically heuristic to "pull out" the order density I will need for integration. I am not 100% sure it is correct.

Now I am trying to come up with a clever way to define the latter probability.
One such way is simply to say that $\alpha$ should fall in the interval between the middle-points of the adjacent order statistics, ie
$$ \frac{X_k + X_{k-1}}{2} < \alpha \land \frac{X_k + X_{k+1}}{2} > \alpha $$

Since joint densities are available, I think I can rewrite this as
$$P(X_k ~\text{closest to } \alpha)=\\
\int I(u+v<2 \alpha) f_{(k,k-1)} d(u,v) \int I(u+v>2 \alpha) f_{(k,k+1)} d(u,v)$$
where $I$ is the indicator function.
These two integrals depend only on $F$ and $\alpha$ and my problem is solved.

The issue is that it is not intuitive. I would like to use the distribution functions and get rid of the indicator function. Basically, I want to know how this Probability changes with
$\alpha$ and $F$ and for different order statistics $k$ - ideally something really nice to look at.
Sadly, I am not very good in statistics so I am somewhat lost.

My questions are

1. Is it correct what I am doing above?
2. Can you think of a clever way to get an expression for $P(X_k ~\text{closest to } \alpha)$ in terms of $F$, order statistic distributions of $F$ and $\alpha$, preferably something which is not a multi-dimensional integral over an indicator?

Comment: In what way do you think, intend, plan or hope (whatever your objective) that the result of your above expectation/integration of the closest order statistic to $\alpha$ will be materially different than $\alpha$ itself? Are you not seeking a complicated process to find what you already know: i.e. the answer is $\alpha$ + a small 'error' term. Presumably, if you take the sample size to be sufficiently large, and you are not focussed on funny extreme values, then that error term can be made to be arbitrarily small.

Comment: Basically, I do not know the specific value of $\alpha$ for observations, the only thing I really have is the distribution. I have some special cases where $alpha$ reduces to 0 and 1 for specific order statistics, in which case I can find analytic results to the question at hand. By showing the above, I know that mixture cases vary continously between extremes (alpha being a weight), and I can gain understanding about the range of outcomes. I supplement this problem with simulations that show that my inference is roughly correct, but I do have to prove that nothing funny happens.

Comment: $\alpha$ determines a choice that affects which order statistic I use to refine F. Integrating over order statistics is the best I can do with the information at hand (at least I think so). If the weights (the probability of being close) change more or less proportionally with these $\alpha$ values, I know that F will be restricted systematically and I know, for example, how skew determines the outcome. I do not have data for the real $\alpha$s, they are latent variables and the $\alpha$ I actually use are a series approximation based on the model logic at hand.